# How to remove a single section from the header of a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Beamer: Frame outside sections?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66628/latex-beamer-frame-outside-sections)

I am using Beamer with the Warsaw theme, and all sections show up in my headline. Is there an easy way to remove them? I have tried using

```
\section*{My section}
```

and this removed them from the TOC, however the trick doesn't apply for the headline.

Thank you for your help,
Tunnuz

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.