# LaTeX Beamer: Frame outside sections?

Tags: beamer, sectioning

At the end of a Beamer presentation, I want a "Thank you for your attention"-slide that is not part of the sections in my presentation. More specifically, I want no section in the navigation bar to be highlighted when I am on that slide. So is there a way to end a section, such that the following slide is not part of that section?

Alternatively, I figured I could make a section that does not appear in the ToC nor in the navigation bar. But I cannot manage to get this done. On [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30056/how-to-remove-a-single-section-from-the-header-of-a-beamer-presentation), it is proposed that one can use

`\section[]*{Starred section}`

but this gives a "*" in the ToC and adds an extra, parasitic slide. An example is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Sec1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame1}
\end{frame}

\section{Sec2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame2}
\end{frame}

\section[]*{Sec3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The last section, Sec3, rightly does not appear in the navigation, but appears as a "*" in the ToC.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to write `\section*{...}` and _not_ `\section[]*{...}`.

Comment: To follow-up on @Thorsten's comment, I *think* I get exactly what you want by writing `\section*{}`.

Comment: You're right; \section*{} (note: No dots between the curly brackets!) produces a section that does not appear in the ToC nor in the navigation bar. Post an answer, and then I'll give you credit. Could someone edit the post I linked to above?

Comment: @user15272 The dots are just a placeholder for your title ...

Comment: @Thorsten: I know, but if I put a title, it does not work: The title goes into the navigation bar. That's why I emphasized that there should be nothing between the curly brackets.

Comment: @user15272 Yes that's right. (I should have read the whole question `:)`)

Comment: @Thorsten: No problem, I thank both you and Andrew Stacey for prompt replies!:-)

Comment: The post you liked to could have a slightly different situation in that it's not clear whether the person wants an empty section title or a section with a title but which doesn't appear in the TOC or the navigation (not clear what value such would have, though).

Comment: He writes explicitly that he wants the section title not to appear in the ToC nor in the navigation bar - So I think it's pretty clear that he asks for exactly the same that I asked for:-)

Comment: I read that as meaning that there is actually a section title, whereas my solution for you works because there is not a section title.  Anyway, I've added a hack for that case as well.

Comment: But I think that one initially thinks that there has to be a title - and that this title should then be "hidden" from the ToC and the navigation bar. That's how I thought about it at first sight at least. However, as we discussed below, the title appears nowhere and consequently one does not need a title. So I think he would be perfectly satisfied with the solution proposed here.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To effectively get a *no section* section, use:

`\section*{}` or `\section{}`

as in the following variant of your code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66628/86}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Sec1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame1}
\end{frame}

\section{Sec2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame2}
\end{frame}

\section{} % or \section*{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: Beamer frame with no section]

As far as I can tell by experimenting, the section command is a bit strange in what it can and cannot accept.  The most general form is `\section<*>[Optional]{Mandatory}`.  *However*, it appears that the `*` and the `Optional` are incompatible (even if the Optional is empty).  So you can have a star or an optional argument, but not both.  With that proviso, the possible combinations are:

- `\section{Text}`: `Text` is in the TOC and the navigation.
- `\section{}`: omitted completely from TOC and navigation (not even allocated space)
- `\section[Text]{Long Text}`: `Long Text` is used in TOC, `Text` in navigation.
- `\section[]{Text}`: `Text` is in the TOC, nothing in navigation.
- `\section[]{}`: Nothing in either place.
- `\section*{}`: omitted completely from TOC and navigation
- `\section*{Text}`: Nothing in TOC, `Text` used in navigation

Here's some test code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66628/86}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{NNT}
\begin{frame}{No Star, No Optional, Text}
\end{frame}

\section{}
\begin{frame}{No Star, No Optional, Empty}
\end{frame}

\section[NOT(S)]{NOT}
\begin{frame}{No Star, Optional, Text}
\end{frame}

\section[NOE]{}
\begin{frame}{No Star, Optional, Empty}
\end{frame}

\section[]{NET}
\begin{frame}{No Star, Empty Optional, Text}
\end{frame}

\section[]{}
\begin{frame}{No Star, Empty Optional, Empty}
\end{frame}

\section*{SNT}
\begin{frame}{Star, No Optional, Text}
\end{frame}

\section*{}
\begin{frame}{Star, No Optional, Empty}
\end{frame}

\section*[SOT(S)]{SOT}
\begin{frame}{Star, Optional, Text}
\end{frame}

\section*[SOE]{}
\begin{frame}{Star, Optional, Empty}
\end{frame}

\section*[]{SET}
\begin{frame}{Star, Empty Optional, Text}
\end{frame}

\section*[]{}
\begin{frame}{Star, Empty Optional, Empty}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

That seems to allow for every possibility *except* that you want to have a section with a proper title which appears neither in the TOC nor in the navigation.  Fortunately, that isn't the case here.  The best I can come up with in that situation is to temporarily disable `\addtocontents` as this inhibits writing to the `toc` file (for the ... wait for it ... table of contents) and the `nav` file (for the navigation bar) but allows everything else to go through.  Looking at the code, at least one of these files is written to if the `\section` command is given any argument whatsoever so this seems to be the only way.  It could be wrapped up a bit more fancily, but in essence it boils down to:

```
\let\origaddtocontents=\addtocontents
\def\dontaddtocontents#1#2{} % or \@gobbletwo if in \makeatletter ... \makeatother

...

\let\addtocontents=\dontaddtocontents
\section{Invisible Section}
\let\addtocontents=\origaddtocontents
```

Comment: Good job! One question: When should you want a section with a proper title that is displayed nowhere? Do the sections play a role anywhere, except in the ToC and in the navigation bar?

Comment: @user15272 I freely admit that I cannot conceive of such a circumstance, unless perhaps the same tex file is being used for both the `beamer` and the `article` mode - but then you can put `\mode<article>{\section{whatever}}`, though that will mess up the section numbering.  There is also the issue of numbered and unnumbered sections which I've not touched on here.

Comment: Any update on this answer for TexLive 2017 and up? `\section*{}` does not work as expected now. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441816/beamer-no-section-section-erratic-behavior-of-section

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the standout frame at the end:

```
\begin{frame}[standout]
Thank you\\ 
for your time!
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I got the following message using 'standout' frame: 'Error: `standout'  undefined in families `beamerframe''

Comment: This is no option which is available per default, but a special feature defined by the metropolis theme.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!