# LaTeX Beamer: Frame outside sections - additional problem with outline between sections

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I refer you to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66628/latex-beamer-frame-outside-sections) to a similar question.

I want exactly what the author of that post wanted, namely a slide with no section in the navigation bar highlighted for that slide. I find that the solution given there does not work for me, presumably because of this code being operative in my case:

```
\AtBeginSubsection
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSection
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
```

I get the desired result of the last frame having no section highlighted in the sidebar. But I get the additional *undesired* result of a outline slide (with all sections shaded).

Below is a full example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Hannover}

\begin{document}


  %=======BEGIN OUTLINE COMMANDS============
\AtBeginSubsection
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSection
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
%=======END OUTLINE COMMANDS============



\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\section{Second Section}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Third Section}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\section*{}

\begin{frame}

Thank you for your attention!

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just redefine `\AtBeginSection` before the final slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Hannover}

\begin{document}


  %=======BEGIN OUTLINE COMMANDS============
\AtBeginSubsection
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSection
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
%=======END OUTLINE COMMANDS============



\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\section{Second Section}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Third Section}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSection{}
\section*{}

\begin{frame}

Thank you for your attention!

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image: Results]

Comment: @user47600 You're welcome. If the solution works for you, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the checkmark. (Disclaimer: I arguably have an interest in this as I will gain 'reputation' if you do so. You will also gain 'reputation' by accepting the solution.) When you gain some more reputation, you will also be able to 'upvote' answers but I think you cannot do that yet. Accepting and/or upvoting answers is the local equivalent of saying 'thanks'. (But I personally still appreciate your saying it regardless of official conventions!)